# Working of a Decorator

Tags: python, return, decorator

I have a question regarding the workings of a decorator. I would like to explain my problem using an example

The code I implemented to understand decorators

```
import sys
import inspect
def entryExit(f):
    def new_f(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:] 
        f(self,*args)        
        print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]        
    return new_f


class A:
    @entryExit
    def move(self,g,h):
        print "hello"        
        print g,h            

    @entryExit    
    def move1(self,m,n):
        print "hello"        
        print m,n
        return m
a=A()
a.move(5,7)
h=a.move1(3,4)
print h
```

The output of this code is

```
Entering move A ['g', 'h']
hello
5 7
Exited move A ['g', 'h']
Entering move1 A ['m', 'n']
hello
3 4
Exited move1 A ['m', 'n']
None
```

The last line of the output displays `None`. But the actual meaning of the method is changed by using decorators. The return statement in the method `move1` was not executed. The actually output I need would be

```
Entering move A ['g', 'h']
hello
5 7
Exited move A ['g', 'h']
Entering move1 A ['m', 'n']
hello
3 4
Exited move1 A ['m', 'n']
3
```

So did I make any mistake while creating a decorator or the  decorators always ignores the return statement in a function?

Comment: Decorators are *just functions*, so you need to treat it like any other chained function call..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the decorator discards the return value of the decorated function.

The following:

```
def new_f(self,*args, **kwargs):
    print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:] 
    f(self,*args)        
    print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]
```

should read:

```
def new_f(self,*args, **kwargs):
    print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:] 
    ret = f(self,*args)        
    print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]        
    return ret
```

Your current code disregards the return value of `f(self,*args)` and implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: @ NPE Thank you so much. It all makes sense now. I have another doubt is it possible to retrieve the parameter name  that was returned during the runtime.

Comment: In my case it would be ´m´. Is it possible to retrieve using the decorator ?

Comment: @karthik: No, that's inside the source of the function. (Why would you need it?)

Comment: @ David Robinson since my work is to parse a python by intrumenting the source code. So i use decorators to insert code into the methods and retrieve the dynamic information during execution. I was able to retrieve all the information except for the parameters that is returned during execution

Comment: @karthik: That sounds... pretty involved. Are you sure you need to insert code into methods dynamically, and that there's not another way to do what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

To let the function return a value, you would have to change the definition of the decorator to be:

```
def new_f(self,*args, **kwargs):
    print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:] 
    ret = f(self,*args)        
    print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]    
    return ret    
return new_f
```

It's not that decorators "always ignore" the return statement, but that you have to handle the return yourself- in the same way that you had to use `*args` and `**kwargs` to handle arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def new_f(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print "Entering", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:] 
        r = f(self,*args)        
        print "Exited", f.__name__,self.__class__.__name__,inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:]  
        return r      
return new_f
```

The return happens when you actually call the function inside the decorator. So, you need to return it from the decorated function too.